# Custom error pages for status codes in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-6.0

Previously, I was able to make an API server returning a custom API response for errors. I had to override a lot of defaults in .NET to return JSON such as:

- Global exception middleware with `UseMiddleware`
- Build status code JSON with a handler using `UseStatusCodePages`
- Configure `ApiBehaviorOptions` so model binding errors return a JSON format that fits my needs

I am now using .NET 6 Razor Pages. I want to return custom error pages for exceptions/errors. I use `UseExceptionHandler` for catching exceptions in the pipeline and it works.

However, errors created by `Configure<FormOptions>` when the `MultipartBodyLengthLimit` upload size is too big as well as `Antiforgery` errors don’t use that, which I understand is by design. Errors like these throw generic 400 Bad Request status codes.

I would like to return a custom response page giving more info with the error message. I don't know where in the pipeline it throws the error and processes it because, [according to the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.formoptions.multipartheaderslengthlimit?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-features-formoptions-multipartheaderslengthlimit), large file uploads should throw `InvalidDataException`.

I’ve tried the following:

- Using a `try/catch` block in the global error handler middleware and inside of `UseStatusCodePages`; neither catch `InvalidDataException`.
- Adding `UseStatusCodePages` to resolve `context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();`, but this comes up empty.
- Adding `AddMvcOptions` with `options.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilter());` and catching inside `OnPageHandlerExecutionAsync`.

I've also looked online for resources, but nothing targets this behavior.

I would like to catch errors thrown by the framework and give the error message telling the reason why instead of just a generic 400 Bad Request. If anyone has some insights into this, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: `UseExceptionHandler` / `UseStatusCodePages` only apply if the response has not started. Which I assume it has?

Comment: FYI `InvalidDataException` is thrown https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Http/WebUtilities/src/MultipartReaderStream.cs#L150 but is translated to `ValueProviderException` https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bec278eabea54f63da15e10e654bdfa4168a2479/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/FormFileValueProviderFactory.cs#L39

Comment: It does seem to hit `UseStatusCodePages` because I can give it a custom handler and log the requests going through it. None of the errors (InvalidDataException and ValueProviderException) seem to catch anything. Thank you for finding that error that's re-thrown though

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked it out.... `UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error")` and `UseExceptionHandler("/Error")` both call the request pipeline *twice*. But [only change](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/backport/pr-36460-to-release/6.0-rc2/src/Middleware/Diagnostics/src/StatusCodePage/StatusCodePagesExtensions.cs#L205) the `.Path` and `.QueryString`.

I believe that anti-forgery errors are triggered during the `.UseEndpoint` middleware, while executing request filters. Any exceptions will be caught before the `EndpointMiddleware` returns.

Since the middleware pipeline is executed twice, any state that would cause an error will need to be cleared. Any time you see that your error page is not used, it is due to the error condition remaining in the state of the `HttpContext`.

So what can we do about it? Raise a bug on github for each situation found. But as a work around, you should probably fork a simpler pipeline so you have more control in how errors or status pages are displayed.

```cs
app.UseStatusCodePages(builder => {
    builder.Use(_next =>
    {
        var eds = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<EndpointDataSource>();

        // find the /Error razor page GET handler
        var endpoint = eds.Endpoints
            .OfType<RouteEndpoint>()
            .Where(e => e.RoutePattern.RawText == "Error")
            .Single();
        var endpointHandler = endpoint.RequestDelegate;

        return async context =>
        {
            // ensure we don't repeat any POST anti-forgery errors
            context.Request.Method = "GET";
            context.SetEndpoint(endpoint);
            await endpointHandler(context);
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean do something like `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error");` and then after it, use a custom `UseExceptionHandler`?

Comment: I just tried what I mentioned above and it didn't work. It just ReExecute to the path of /Error, skipping the exception handler, I don't see a way to grab the error